SwiftUI unexpected body render
I'm trying to understand how SwiftUI decides whether or not to re-render a view;
In this example I have a PageView which shows horizontal scrollable pages through a DragGesture for every week, very similar to UIPageViewController.
The view accepts an @escaping closure that will render each page based on the returned value, in this case I'm using a week object that represent a week of a month.
store object is a StateObject that contains a single @Published var state: ViewState and it dispatches events, very similar to a Redux implementation.
The issue is that if I write the view in this way, during the scroll the body of PageContentView is called constantly making the app glitching:
  @ViewBuilder
  private var pagedView: some View {
    PageView(
      selectedItem: store.binding(
        get: \.selectedWeek,
        dispatch: { .onWeekChange($0) }
      ),
      dataSource: .init(
        previousItem: store.state.previousWeek,
        nextItem: store.state.nextWeek
      )
    ) { week in
      let viewState = store.state.viewState(for: week)
      PageContentView(
        week: week,
        state: viewState,
        scrollTarget: store.binding(get: \.scrollTarget, dispatch: { .onScrollTargetChange($0) }),
        onRefresh: {
          store.dispatch(event: .onWeekRefresh(week, $0))
        },
        didTapShift: { shift in
          store.dispatch(event: .onShiftTap(shift))
        },
        didTapCreateShift: {
          store.dispatch(event: .onCreateShiftTap)
        },
        didTapClearFilters: {
          store.dispatch(event: .onClearFiltersTap)
        }
      )
      .animation(.spring, value: viewState)
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
      todayButton
    }
    .animation(nil, value: store.state.snackBarModels)
  }

But, if I extract values at top like this, it doesn't unnecessarily call view's body, making everything super smooth
  @ViewBuilder
  private var pagedView: some View {
    let scrollTarget = store.binding(get: \.scrollTarget, dispatch: { .onScrollTargetChange($0) })
    let store = store
    PageView(
      selectedItem: store.binding(
        get: \.selectedWeek,
        dispatch: { .onWeekChange($0) }
      ),
      dataSource: .init(
        previousItem: store.state.previousWeek,
        nextItem: store.state.nextWeek
      )
    ) { week in
      let viewState = store.state.viewState(for: week)
      PageContentView(
        week: week,
        state: viewState,
        scrollTarget: scrollTarget,
        onRefresh: {
          store.dispatch(event: .onWeekRefresh(week, $0))
        },
        didTapShift: { shift in
          store.dispatch(event: .onShiftTap(shift))
        },
        didTapCreateShift: {
          store.dispatch(event: .onCreateShiftTap)
        },
        didTapClearFilters: {
          store.dispatch(event: .onClearFiltersTap)
        }
      )
      .animation(.spring, value: viewState)
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
      todayButton
    }
    .animation(nil, value: store.state.snackBarModels)
  }

As you can see now scrollTarget binding is created once and then passed to the closure, hence SwiftUI in some way decides the object didn't change (and it makes sense actually, as in the example before I was creating a binding at each call of the closure).
The thing I can't understand is why if I just make a local let store = store, which is a class type and then pass down to the closure of PageView, it doesn't call body on each drag anymore. What am I missing?

StateObject.wrappedValue is one of the ways that SwiftUI finds dependencies between views and data. The difference between the two snippets is that you are no longer getting the wrappedValue of a @StateObject in the trailing closure passed to PageView.init. As a result, SwiftUI no longer thinks that store is a dependency of PageContentView. Without seeing a [mcve], I cannot go into more detail.
